# How to import a js file which is generated by a webpack plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am writing a webpack plugin which is used to generated a javascript file on the disk. It works fine but I don't know how to import this file on js my source code. The plugin configuration in webpack looks like below:

```
new MyModuleWebpackPlugin({
  filename: '/my-module.js',
  minify: true,
}),
```

when I run `webpack` command, the file `my-moudle.js` file will be generated under `dist` directory. But how can I import this file in my js file? If I do import as below webpack will complain that can't resolve the path `../dist/my-module.js`.

```
import MyModuel from '../dist/my-module.js'
```

I wander how to do that in webpack package process.